# Fritzing doesn't treat breadboard power rails as conductors

Tags: schematics, breadboard

I'm starting with Fritzing and created a simple schematic. All good. Now I want to turn in into a breadboard layout for my son to follow.

All the components are there and connected with dotted lines. Now I can't figure out how to make Fritzing understand that all the power rails and the vertical 5-holes are like wires? It insist on connecting all the components and power supply with explicit wires instead of letting me run the power supply to the top and bottom power rails and feed the circuit from there. Same with connecting resistors, capacitors, etc. Fritzing seems to disregard the breadbord internal connectors and insists on running wires everywhere.

Must be a some simple trick somewhere but I can't figure out what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out I have to start the connection from the breadbord to the component - then Fritzing highlights the breadboard holes and treats them as a conductor. If I start from the component it tends to create a "wire" between components and disregard the breadboard matrix. Weird but can get used to it ;)